# How to calibrate orientation sensors in android

Tags: java, android, sensors

I'm trying to get data from my phone's gyros.
So far,the angles keep changing depends on the angle that i move my phone.

However, the azimuth angle for example, i want it to start counting from the position i started and not from the north direction --> i want it to start from 0.

my question is: how can i save the first data i get from the gyro so i could do "minus" from the rest of the data when i move the phone?
The code looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    rotationvector=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    sm.registerListener(this,rotationvector,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    rotationx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rotationx);
    rotationy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rotationy);
    rotationz=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rotationz);


}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    rotationx.setText(" " +event.values[0]);
    rotationy.setText(" " +event.values[1]);
    rotationz.setText(" " +event.values[2]);

}
```

The thing i want to do is like:

```
    rotationx.setText(" " +event.values[0]-FirstAzimuthValue);
```

Thanks!

new code:

```
private boolean isFirstMeasure = true;
private float FirstAzimuthValue = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    rotationvector=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    sm.registerListener(this,rotationvector,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    rotationx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rotationx);
    rotationy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rotationy);
    rotationz=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rotationz);

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (isFirstMeasure){
        FirstAzimuthValue - event.values[0]; //error this line
        isFirstMeasure = false;
    }

    rotationx.setText(" " +(event.values[0] - FirstAzimuthValue));
    rotationy.setText(" " +event.values[1]);
    rotationz.setText(" " +event.values[2]);

}
```

Comment: Check the angle in the onCreate function and save it into a variable named firstazimuthvalue, then do with it whatever you want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
private boolean isFirstMeasure = true;
private float firstAzimuthValue = 0;

// ...

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (isFirstMeasure) {
        firstAzimuthValue = event.values[0];
        isFirstMeasure = false;
    }

    rotationx.setText(" " + (event.values[0] - firstAzimuthValue));
    rotationy.setText(" " +event.values[1]);
    rotationz.setText(" " +event.values[2]);
}
```

Comment: Hey antonio, i tried to do what u said, it gives 2 problems: 1) in the if statement it says "not a statement". 2) at rotationx it dont let to do "minus" on floating.

Comment: Second problem solved with my edit (my mistake). The first problem must be a misunderstanding. Could you post your new code?

Comment: Fixed my typo, try again. Sorry

Comment: did you check the output values ?, it goes to zero after it reaches angle 64 value